# Loading a modal within a rails form. Custom stripe form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

i'm trying to load a payment form within a modal within a rails form.  As it is right now, when I click "Buy Now" the modal will load, but the form will submit.  How do I have it not submit until, the someone clicks "Submit" in the modal.

```
        = form_tag foo_path, id: 'payment-form' do
      -if @store.products == nil 
        Test
      - @store.products.each_with_index do |product, index|
        .row
          .col-lg-2
            - if current_user
              - if store.user_id == current_user.id
                = link_to "Delete", product_path(product), data: { method: "delete", confirm: "Are you sure?"}
          .col-lg-8
            .panel.panel-default
              .panel-body
                .row
                  .col-lg-2
                    %input{:type => "checkbox", :id => "switchName#{index}", :class => "check"}/
                    %label{:for => "switchName#{index}"}
                  .col-lg-8
                    = hidden_field_tag("order_products[][product_id]", product.id)
                    = product.name
                    %br
                    .subheader= number_to_currency(product.cost_in_cents.to_f / 100)

                  .col-lg-2
                    = select_tag("order_products[][quanity]", options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]), "data-cost-per-unit" => product.cost_in_cents, id: product.name, class: "drop", :prodindex => index)
          .col-lg-2
      -if current_user
      -else
        %span.payment-errors
          .text-center
            %h2.total-amount        
              Total:  
              $0.00
          %hr
            .text-center
              %button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg{"data-target" => "#myModal", "data-toggle" => "modal"}
                Buy Now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when clicking on a `<button>` element, the containing form is submitted: [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

If you use `{"data-target" => "#myModal", "data-toggle" => "modal", "type" => "button"}` when creating your button, it should display your modal without submitting the form.

Then, you'll have to handle submitting the form in your modal if that's what you want to happen.

Comment: Great, that works. Now my form will not submit inside of my modal.  Is there something else I have to do add inside of the modal?  My submit tag inside of my modal looks like this: `%button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"} Pay Now!`  Once clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: As long as your modal is inside of your opening and closing `<form> ... </form>` tags, it should work.